# Defining a new 3-column glossaries style

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392918/how-to-set-up-a-japanese-to-english-glossary) question about setting up a Japanese-English glossary (which will in fact be a Japanese-French one, but that doesn't change much), I need to define a new style for this glossary. For now, the `altlong4col-booktabs` seems to be the closest to what I'd like the result to be. However, I need to add a few changes :

1. Remove the "Page List" column,
2. Rename the headers,
3. Make the first column ("Notation") bold,
4. And invert the positions of the "Description" and "Symbol" columns.

Here is what I have for now :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[automake, style=index, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra} 
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

\setmainlanguage{french}
\setCJKmainfont{AozoraMinchoRegular.ttf}

\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{altlong4col-booktabs}

%syntax: \newterm[options]{romaji}{original}{translation}
\newcommand{\newterm}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{%
    name={#2},% romanized version
    symbol={#3},% original
    description={#4},% translation
    #1% extra options
  }%
}

\newcommand{\glsxtrpostlinkgeneral}{%
  \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
  {%
    \glsxtrifwasfirstuse
    {%
      \ifglshassymbol{\glslabel}{\space(\glsaccesssymbol{\glslabel},
        «~\glsaccessdesc{\glslabel}~»)}{}%
    }%
    {}%
  }%
  {}%
}

% use \emph in the document (but not in the glossary)
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrregularfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\newterm{bakumatsu}{幕末}{fin du shogunat}

\begin{document}   
The \gls{bakumatsu} era.  

Next use: \gls{bakumatsu}.

\printglossary[title=Glossaire des termes japonais]
\end{document}
```

This prints the following result :

[image: Main text]
[image: Glossary]

The glossary style I would like to define should look like this somehow (don't mind the font) : 
[image: Desired glossary style]

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a style that creates a three-column glossary. (You still need to load `glossary-longbooktabs` which defines `\glspatchLToutput` and also loads `booktabs` and `longtable`.)

```
\newglossarystyle{romaji}{%
  \glspatchLToutput
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{.33\textwidth}p{.33\textwidth}>{\raggedright}p{.33\textwidth}}}%
    {\end{longtable}}%
% Table header:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{\toprule\bfseries Transcription en
  caractères latins (\emph{rōmaji}) &
  \bfseries Ecriture japonaise &
  \bfseries Traduction\tabularnewline\midrule\endhead\bottomrule\endfoot}%
% No letter group headings:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
% Top-level (no parent) entries:
% (#1 is the entry's label)
% (#2 is the numberlist which is ignored here)
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
% Romanized name (in bold):
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\textbf{\glossentryname{##1}}} &
% Original Japanese:
    \glossentrysymbol{##1} &
% Translation:
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
% Sub-level (has parent) entries (just do the same as top-level):
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
% Gap between letter groups (governed by nogroupskip package option):
  \ifglsnogroupskip
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \else
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{ & & & \tabularnewline}%
  \fi
}
```

Use `\setglossarystyle` rather than the deprecated `\glossarystyle`:

```
\setglossarystyle{romaji}
```

or use the `style` key in `\printglossary` (which will localise the patch introduced with `\glspatchLToutput`):

```
\printglossary[title=Glossaire des termes japonais,style=romaji]
```

I've made all three columns equal width using:

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{.33\textwidth}p{.33\textwidth}>{\raggedright}p{.33\textwidth}}
```

You may need to adjust these settings.

If I add the above style to the code in your question (and substitute the CJK font with one installed on my computer) I get:

[image: image of document with three-column glossary]